# Will a function be non differentiable at point not in domain

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives, continuity

What is correct to say among non-differentiable or cannot be decided for a point which isn’t in domain for a function
Example f(x)=x for all x belongs to real numbers except 1
So will we say it is non-differentiable at x=1 ?

Comment: Asking whether a function $f\colon X\to Y$ is differentiable at some $z\notin X$ is meaningless. It is neither differentiable nor not-differentiable at points outside of the domain: it isn't defined there.

Comment: There is a hidden question here which is of some interest though @Christoph is spot on for what is asked. It is sometimes useful to ask the question whether a function which is defined on some domain can be extended to a function on a larger domain and whether it can retain its good properties when it is so extended.  Here the function is undefined and doesn't exist at $x=1$. It can be extended in various ways to the whole real line (just choose a value for $f(1)$), but only one of those extensions is continuous and differentiable at $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks for helping @Christoph
It was in one of the questions in my test which required to find number of non differentiable points in (-pi,pi) for max{tanx,cotx} 
The answer was given 7 so I asked 
Answer might be wrong 

Comment: You could argue with that answer $7$, since it counts points like $x=0$ where the function is $\infty$.  Maybe the question is for meromorphic functions, and allows functions to have the value $\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

> DEFINITION: Suppose a function $\phi$ is defined in an open
> neighbourhood of $a$. We say that $\phi$ is *differentiable* at $a$ if
> $$ \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\phi(a+h)-\phi(a)}{h} $$ exists.

The function $f$ is not defined at $1$, and so $f$ is not defined in an open neighbourhood of $1$. Hence, the definition of differentiability does not even apply to $f$. This is like asking whether the number $2.7$ is odd or even.